# C++ make all pointers invalid if object was deleted

Tags: c++

I have class BaseStream, and function which make new BaseStream. Also i have another class with BaseStream* field. How can i know is this field valid or not, because instance of BaseStream* can be deleted somewhere

p.s. I can't use std: and c++11

Comment: You can't. Not with raw pointers anyway. I suggest you use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). A weak_ptr from such shared_ptr should allow you to know if the object was released.

Comment: @Borgleader But the `delete` might have to be through a raw pointer.  (`delete this` is very frequent, for example, and `this` cannot be a smart pointer.)  More generally, such problems occur when the object has a lifetime defined by the application logic (which means that you can't manage it with smart pointers).

Comment: @JamesKanze why objects with lifetime "defined by application logic" cannot be managed with smart pointers?

Comment: Because smart pointers don't respect the application logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three choices:

1. Use the *observer pattern*, so objects can be notified if another object is about to be destroyed.
2. Use `boost::shared_ptr`.
3. Implement your own smart pointer class.

(1) is fun to implement and you can retain your bare pointers which you might find is necessary depending on how your application has been written. (2) could work (subject to my previous remarks) and would enable you do drop in `std::shared_ptr` once you've migrated to C++11. (3) is too much reinventing the wheel and smart pointer classes are difficult to get right.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Re 3: `shared_ptr` is only applicable in very limited cases.  (And it's not that difficult to get them right if you're writing your own.  Which is generally preferable, since the semantics of `std::shared_ptr` are rather dangerous as long as raw pointers to the object, like `this` can still exist.)

Comment: Indeed. With `std::shared_ptr` you either use it wholeheartedly or not at all. I think in this case (1) is the way I'd go.

Comment: There are two problems with using it wholeheartedly.  The first is that you can't make `this` a shared pointer; if you have member functions which are involved in non-trivial communications with other objects, then you're stuck.  The second is that it doesn't handle cycles.

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions.  The most robust is to use the Boehm
collector for recycling memory; in this manner, you can
overwrite the object with something recognizable as a deleted
object in the destructor, and you are guaranteed that the memory
won't be recycled as long as there is a pointer to it, so you
can test before any use whether the object has been deleted or
not.

In general, however, you should avoid the problem; the use of
the Boehm collector, as above, should really be a back-up
measure, and accessing the destructed object should be treated
as an internal software error, like an assertion failure.  Use
the observer pattern: any code which has a pointer to the object
registers with it as an observer, and the object notifies them
in its destructor, so they can reset the pointer (or remove it
from a map or a vector, or whatever they have to do).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

Comment: Plus one, the Boehm Collector is very posh indeed. If you don't mind, I've added a reference. I know that's not to everyone's taste. If you don't like it, then please take it down or ask me to do it.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just the opposite; I was just too lazy to get the reference.  It's a very useful tool, especially for cases where you need the checking.  (The nature of C++ results in practically no "garbage" getting created, so you rarely need it for "garbage collection" in the strict sense of the term.  But ensuring that the memory of deleted objects is not recycled as long as there is a pointer to them is a powerful tool for defensive programming.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use raw pointers you cannot know if a member is valid. When a member is deleted "somewhere" accessing it is undefined behaviour.
This is good argument to use shared and weak pointers (which solve your problem). If you cannot use library ones, write your own specialised ones. But without wrapper objects of some type you cannot check member validity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66737/discussion-on-answer-by-wojtek-surowka-c-make-all-pointers-invalid-if-object-w).